# eslint error Unary operator '++' used no-plusplus

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, eslint

I am getting error with my for loop if I used `i++` in for `loop`

```
var foo = 0;
    foo++;
    
    var bar = 42;
    bar--;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined? Why is there a return statement inside the loop? -- Ah, the example is from https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus

Comment: The return statement should only appear within the body of a function.

Comment: @MehpalPatidar please consider ticking one of the answers below

Comment: Notice that this is not a programming error per se. It is just that your default configuration and/or the coding style you are using does not allow prefix/postfix increment/decrement operators. Anyways, as pointed out in some answers, you can replace `i++` with `i += 1` to get rid of the violation.

Answer (score 31):

One option would be to replace `i++` with `i+=1`

You can also turn that specific eslint rule off (either for the specific line, the file or global configuration). Please consider that this might be **not recommended**, especially at the file or line level.

The rule name you are looking for is **no-plusplus**.

**Disable it globally**

In your eslint config file add the following:

```
'no-plusplus': 'off' **OR** 'no-plusplus': 0
```

There is also an option to disable it only for the for loops:

```
 no-plusplus: ["error", { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }]
```

For further information you can check [eslint no-plusplus docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus)

**Disable it at the file level**

At the top of your file add the following:

```
/* eslint-disable no-plusplus */
```

**Disable it for the given line**

Just before the for loop, add the following:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus */
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you. How could I forgot about `i+=1`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the return value of ++ is not equal to +=.

Comment: Thank you, is it me or is this rule just nonsense?

Answer (score 6):

I got solution of this problem

if we are use i++ in our code eslint give error. For avoiding this type of error we have to use

```
var foo = 0;
foo += 1;

var bar = 42;
bar -= 1;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    return;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what about ++i?

Answer (score 6):

**eslint no-plusplus: "error"**

Will throw the error on following instances

```
var foo = 0;
foo++;

var bar = 42;
bar--;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    return;
}
```

Use as follows to fix the lint issues so it will go by the rules

```
var foo = 0;
foo += 1;

var bar = 42;
bar -= 1;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    return;
}
```

[Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see this is a linting error. Either write the code like this,

`foo += 1;`

and

```
i += 1
```

Or turn that eslint rule off. (not a good idea);

Answer (score 0):

As per Eslint doc, using these operators are subject to automatic semicolon insertion and differences in whitespace can change the semantics of source code.

So it is not allowed in eslint rule, but you can ignore it using this line:

```
/* eslint no-plusplus: "error" */
```

for reference eslint doc: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus